# What is the right way of reading binary data from google bucket in google cloud function using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying with the below code to read the content of the file. I'm able to read the data but after reading if I'm trying to extract it facing illegal offset error.

```
function getFileContent(fileName, bucketName) {
  const storage = new Storage();
  const file =  storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName);
  const content =await file.download();
  content.toString('utf-8');
  return content;
}
//channel.tx contains the bytes, is there any specific way to read file which is in bytes?
    let envelope_bytes = await getFileContent("/channel-artifacts/channel.tx", "fabriccerts");
    const Client = require('fabric-client');
    const client = new Client();
    let config_update = client.extractChannelConfig(envelope_bytes); //throwing illegal offset error here.
```

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Show the code where the error is happening. Your problem sounds like you have read the object. If you want to read the object again, either open the object again and read, or reset the file offset pointer back to zero. Your code does not show what you are doing other than to simply read the object and return the content.

Comment: As John said, share your code where the error is happening and the exact message you are getting. This way it could be faster to help you.

Comment: I have added the code as suggested. @SamuelRomero